Login with facebook confirmation dialog on mobile
I'm implementing a website with React frontend and Java (spring-boot) as a backend.
I've implemented a 'Login with Facebook' button which works great on desktop:

upon first login it takes me to facebook to Allow it
upon subsequent login it doesn't take me to facebook to Allow it, but instead redirects be back to my website's /account page and i'm already logged in.

On mobile however this is what happens:

every time I click 'Login with facebook' it redirects me to Facebook in order to 'Allow' the access. Every single time it shows this dialog:


Why it doesn't behave like the desktop? I would like it to stop showing me this dialogue after the first time I have granted access.
Is it a setting in Facebook? Or maybe my oauth request url is missing a parameter?
